# CAShapeLayer in Interface Builder?

Tags: ios, ios8, xcode6

I'm creating a custom keyboard.

Option A - Create graphics for the keys that support all the platform. Create separate graphics for landscape mode - and swap them into place when keyboard rotates.

I'd prefer to not have to create graphics.

Option B - Build custom UIView class that utilizes CAShapeLayer to create the keys and resize accordingly when keyboard is rotated.

My problem is I would have to write a lot of code to position all of the keys programmatically.

Does it make sense to layout the custom views in Interface Builder, size them appropriately, and just have my shape layer match the bounds of the view?

Or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd build two XIBs - one for Landscape, one for Portrait and swap them on rotation.

Given we may or may not see different screen sizes with the iPhone6, I'd ultimately opt for Option B, write the code once and be happy to be iPhone6 ready on day 1.